# Accessing view objects from appWidgetProvider

Tags: android, widget

I am trying to write a simple android widget and I have the following problem.

I am trying to access a textView from the appWidgetProvider class in order to set the font to a custom typeface. The code looks like the following:

```
TextView mytext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext); 
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/custom-font.ttf"); 
mytext.setTypeface(typeface);
```

The problem is that findViewById is not defined in the appWidgetProvider object. So how do I do this? I have found that you can do this by creating a canvas and drawing the custom font to an ImageView but this is not a good solution. Is there a way to do this with textView? If it can be done in an activity, why can't it be done in a widget?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So how do I do this?

You can't. You will have to stick to the built-in fonts for your app widgets, until such time as they add `setTypeface()` support to `RemoteViews`.

> If it can be done in an activity, why can't it be done in a widget?

Because the app widget's `Views` are not in your process. They are in the home screen's process.